# Simple log function in Bash

Tags: bash

I am just getting a little more comfortable with Bash.

I wanted a super simple log function to write to a file and output to the console for messages and errors. I also wanted the terminal and the file to interpret newline characters rather than printing them out.
Here is what I came up with (it works fine):

```
#!/bin/bash

log () {
  if [[ "$3" == '-e' || "$3" == '--error' ]]; then
    >&2 echo -e "ERROR: $1" && printf "ERROR: $1\n" >> "$2"
  else
    echo -e "$1" && printf "$1\n" >> "$2"
  fi
}

# Example implementation
log_file=snip/init.log
msg="\nthis is an error message with leading newline character"
log "$msg" $log_file -e
msg="this is success message with no newline characters"
log "$msg" $log_file
```

I don't need any more functionality however I have some questions:

1. Is an efficient and readable piece of code that won't break when passed strings with special characters?
2. Syntactically, could I have done this 'better' such as using pipes instead of `&&`. `tee` instead of `printf` etc.?
3. How can I refactor this code to allow for the optional `-e` flag to be passed in first?

Comment: Just as a small note, I'd switch the arguments around to `log [OPTIONS] LOG_FILE MESSAGE...". So when called it would look like this `log "$log_file" "Part1" "Part 2" "and so on"` or `log --error "$log_file" "Part1" "Part 2" "and so on"`.

Comment: @Bobby yeah I should swap the FILE and MSG arguments around. I do not know how to allow for the optional -e flag to be the first argument though since it may or may not be passed into the log function.

Comment: You could easily pass `-e` first, using `if` and `shift`.  But it might be better to have two different functions, and that's what I propose in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's quite a bit of repetition:

- `echo && print` with roughly the same arguments - `tee` is probably better here
- error and non-error paths - perhaps use one function to prepend the `ERROR:` tag and call the other?

It might be best to have the filename first, then any number of message words?  That would make the interface more like `echo`, for example.

There's also a problem with our use of `printf` - any `%` characters in the error message will be interpreted as replacement indicators.  Not what we want.  We could use `printf %b` to expand escape sequences instead:

```
# log FILE MESSAGE...
log () {
    local file="$1"; shift
    printf '%b ' "$@" '\n' | tee -a "$file"
}

# log_err FILE MESSAGE...
log_error () {
    local file="$1"; shift
    local message="ERROR: $1"; shift
    log "$file" "$message" "$@" >&2
}
```

If we do want to have a single function with arguments (e.g. to add more options), then we might want to use the `while`/`case` approach of option parsing that's often used at the program level:

```
#!/bin/bash

set -eu

# log [-e] [-f FILE] MESSAGE...
log() {
    local prefix=""
    local stream=1
    local files=()
    # handle options
    while ! ${1+false}
    do case "$1" in
        -e|--error) prefix="ERROR:"; stream=2 ;;
        -f|--file) shift; files+=("${1-}") ;;
        --) shift; break ;; # end of arguments
        -*) log -e "log: invalid option '$1'"; return 1;;
        *) break ;; # start of message
       esac
       shift
    done
    if ${1+false}
    then log -e "log: no message!"; return 1;
    fi
    # if we have a prefix, update our argument list
    if [ "$prefix" ]
    then set -- "$prefix" "$@"
    fi
    # now perform the action
    printf '%b ' "$@" '\n' | tee -a "${files[@]}" >&$stream
}
```

There's a non-obvious trick in there that might need explanation: I've used `${1+false}` to expand to `false` when there's at least one argument remaining, or to an empty command when there are no arguments (empty command is considered "true" by `if` and `while`).

Comment: I think I need to keep this code in one single function though since I will have another log function for logging to only a file (no console), I call that function `log_silent`. The thing is I dont really want 4 functions to get this job done. I would like to do this with just two functions.

Comment: Yes, `local` and `tee -a` and the newline are all good improvements (I should have tried the code before publishing!).  Edited.

Comment: I've updated to show how you can parse options in a single function.  It should be easy to add a "silent" option that sets `stream=/dev/null`.